# Write Python variable to new cell in each column in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I want to use BeautifulSoup with Python to scraping data from dynamic website. Everything compile ok, I can get correct the value in  tag to output and write down to csv. But the problem in here is that, instead of write the value to each rows of column, but when I open csv file, I see that my code just write value to only one column, but in my case I have 9 columns. I don't know how to put value from variable to separate columns???

```
with open('myreport.csv','wb') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    thewriter.writerow(['Toan','Van','Ngoai ngu','Vat li','Hoa hoc','Sinh hoc','Lich su','Dia li','GDCD'])
```

And my code to get value of all  tag I need.

```
for row in rows:    
        content1 = row.find_all('td')[1::2]
        for content2 in content1:
            print(content2.get_text())
            thewriter.writerow([content2.get_text()])
```

The csv file structure I expect is that:

```
'Toan','Van','Ngoai ngu','Vat li','Hoa hoc','Sinh hoc','Lich su','Dia li','GDCD'
'8','7','2','5','4','10'
```

But when compile complete, it return that:

```
'Toan','Van','Ngoai ngu','Vat li','Hoa hoc','Sinh hoc','Lich su','Dia li','GDCD'
'8'
'7'
'2'
'5'
'4'
'10'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
thewriter.writerow([content2.get_text()])
```

This code write one single value out as a row. What you want is all of them:

```
content1 = row.find_all('td')[1::2]
all_cells = [c.get_text() for c in content1]
thewriter.writerow(all_cells)
```

Comment: for row in rows: 
     content1 = row.find_all('td')[1::2]
     all_cells = [c.get_text() for c in content1]
     thewriter.writerow(all_cells)

Comment: What does not work? Did you get error? What's the output looks like?

Comment: Hi, thanks. After brainstorm myself, I have figure out the problem!